# How to return function in $q defer.resolve?

Tags: angularjs

*edit*
i succeed to solve it:
i used `defer.resolve(SomeFunction)`

There is a way to return a function in $q, defer.resolve?

I already tried this:

```
function SomeFunctino(){
   return $q(
     getfromDB.then(functino(result) = {
       ...
       resolve()
     }).catch(functino (error) {
       console.log(error);
       reject();
     });
   );
}    

funcion getPromise(){
  let defer = $q.defer();
  defer.resolve = SomeFunction //the function return promise
  return defer.promise;
}

let promise = getPromise();
promise.then((value) => { //value = undefined
   value.then(() => {...}
});
```

when i did it like that the value is undefined (and if i return string instead of a function its work).

Comment: how is your `someFunction()` defined?

Comment: @RaviShankar i edited my post and added this function

Comment: [are you sure that you need `$q`](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/%24q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/)? If you are using `$http`, it already returns a Promise that can be resolved

Comment: there is a typo in the code, `functino` instead of `function`. Do you think thats not an error?

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should add that information as an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$q.when` to return a promise that resolves with a function:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($q) {
    function someFunction (x) {
        return x*x;
    }

    var promise = $q.when(someFunction);

    promise.then(function (fn) {
        console.log(fn(5));  // 25
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">

</body>
```